# How to use eloquent "with" to pass array of multiple arrays for looping

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a page which has different uls for different filtered rows in a single SQL table. I've been trying and searching for the last couple hours to see how I could provide the view with the multiple arrays using "with", I'm going to get straight into posting the code so it can provide a better idea of what I'm trying to do. With each array using different SQL params, I wasn't sure how to collect all of them into a single variable, so I decided to pass it as an array

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Activity;

class ActivityController extends Controller
{
    public function index (){
        $activities[] = [
            'yearlies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'yearly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(6),
            'monthlies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'monthly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(4),
            'weeklies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'weekly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(4),
        ];
        return view('activities')->with('activities', $activities);
    }
}
```

On the client side I want to loop through each variable to put them into each UL

```
<div class="row pt-2">
            @if(count($yearlies) > 0)
                @foreach($activities['yearlies'] as $yearly)
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/{{$yearly->activity_picture_link}}" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{$yearly->name}}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{$yearly->activity_desc_short}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                @if ($yearly->activity_free === true)
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Free</h6></li>
                                @else
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">${{$yearly->activity_low_cost}} - ${{$yearly->activity_high_cost}}</h6></li>
                                @endif
                            </ul>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <a href="/activities/{{$yearly->id}}" class="card-link">View Activity</a>
                                <a href="/" class="card-link float-right">Save</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <h5 class="text-secondary text-center">No yearlies available</h5>
            @endif
        </div>
```

Hopefully it is somewhat apparent what I'm trying to do. Regardless, I've been searching and all I see is stuff about collections but I'm not personally defining the different sub-values so I can't utilize the => functionality they do. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Below is the dd of $activities, I would like to know how to navigate to each yearlies row through this

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "yearlies" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#262 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => App\Activity {#295 ▼
          #table: "activities"
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:14 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "name"
            "activity_desc_short" => "desc"
            "activity_desc" => "desc"
            "activity_free" => 0
            "activity_low_cost" => "10.50"
            "activity_high_cost" => "20.50"
            "activity_feature_type" => "yearly"
            "activity_daily_budget" => "3.00"
            "activity_picture_link" => null
            "activity_posting_business" => ""
            "location" => null
            "created_at" => "2020-01-16 21:22:18"
            "updated_at" => "2020-01-16 21:22:18"
          ]
          #original: array:14 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #fillable: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
      ]
    }
    "monthlies" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#288 ▶}
    "weeklies" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#298 ▶}
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are sending value in one array variable, that means it is multi-dimensional array.

Also, instead of

```
$activities[] = [
            'yearlies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'yearly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(6),
            'monthlies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'monthly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(4),
            'weeklies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'weekly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(4),
        ];
```

Use

```
$activities = [
            'yearlies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'yearly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(6),
            'monthlies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'monthly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(4),
            'weeklies' => Activity::all()
                ->where('activity_feature_type', 'weekly')
                ->sortByDesc('activity_daily_budget')
                ->take(4),
        ];
```

which will reduce complexity of an array.

Also, in your `blade` file -

```
<div class="row pt-2">
            @if(isset($activities) || $activities!= null)
                @foreach($activities['yearlies'] as $yearly)
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/{{$yearly->activity_picture_link}}" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{$yearly->name}}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{$yearly->activity_desc_short}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                @if ($yearly->activity_free === true)
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Free</h6></li>
                                @else
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">${{$yearly->activity_low_cost}} - ${{$yearly->activity_high_cost}}</h6></li>
                                @endif
                            </ul>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <a href="/activities/{{$yearly->id}}" class="card-link">View Activity</a>
                                <a href="/" class="card-link float-right">Save</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <h5 class="text-secondary text-center">No yearlies available</h5>
            @endif
        </div>
```

I guess this will work fine. If I am wrong please correct me. Hope this works for you.

Comment: This returned an error; count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: Then instead of ```count``` directly use it. I will edit my answer. You can try that.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is up and running as intended!

Answer (score 1):

```
div class="row pt-2">
            @if(count($yearlies) > 0)
                @foreach($activities->yearlies as $yearly)
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/{{$yearly->activity_picture_link}}" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{$yearly->name}}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{$yearly->activity_desc_short}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                @if ($yearly->activity_free === true)
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">Free</h6></li>
                                @else
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><h6 class="font-weight-bold">${{$yearly->activity_low_cost}} - ${{$yearly->activity_high_cost}}</h6></li>
                                @endif
                            </ul>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <a href="/activities/{{$yearly->id}}" class="card-link">View Activity</a>
                                <a href="/" class="card-link float-right">Save</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <h5 class="text-secondary text-center">No yearlies available</h5>
            @endif
        </div>
```

try this

Comment: This returns "Trying to get property 'yearlies' of non-object"